# DMG or Zip file for distribution to Macs?

Tags: macos, zip, dmg

What do you prefer and why?

I've just finished my first Mac app and am wondering if this is an important decision.

Answer (score 7):

Interestingly, I was just reading this, having been referred to it this morning. 
http://daringfireball.net/2009/09/how_should_mac_apps_be_distributed

I like .dmg file distributions because they present a diskette or disc metaphor with which I am comfortable.

I can attest that the presented .dmg top level finder window does confuse some. The .zip file distributions tend to be clearer to those people.

Comment: I don't think it's just a metaphor – as I understand it, the OS thinks it *is* a disk!

Answer (score 5):

I've always liked DMG better. You don't have to worry about filesystem clutter of extracted files, since you can just unmount the image when you're done installing it.

If the installation process for your app is of the "just put it in Applications" variety, you can also provide an alias to that folder in the DMG, which makes things really straightforward.

Comment: I think the Thunderbird DMG I recently installed from overdid things a little, though: they had some really fancy background with an arrow, so the window looked rather more like installation instructions than something I could actually manipulate!

Answer (score 1):

Zip needs drive space to expand, since it actually makes a new directory to duplicate in larger format what is in the archive. DMG works similar to connecting a thumb drive – no startup volume space is needed, until you drag the needed files to the internal drive.

These folks who put an arrow image in their DMG window should add the words "DRAG TO APPLICATIONS" to the arrow, because I promise you, a surprising percentage of new-to-Mac folks miss the idea, as one commenter here said.

There is also some increased security process for DMG. There is a level of verification that does not occur with a Zip. It is possible for a Zip to be programmed to self-expand and the contents can be programmed to self-install. Ask any long-time PC user.

One comment mentions distinguishing an installer from an app. In Windows, they both look the same (filename.exe), but in OS X, an app SHOULD be a ready to use bundle. An installer should be filename.pkg (installer package) or filename.mpkg (multi-package – 2 or more packages that typically run in series). The routine is for .app, drag to Applications directory; for .pkg or .mpkg, double-click right there in the disk image window. Sometimes a developer will pull a fast one, and use an app bundle as an installer. They should be forced to walk the plank.